# Visual Studio loses bindings to TFS suddenly

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, binding, tfs

Why would my VS solution lose its TFS bindings suddenly? I have been working on a project for six months and this never happened. As soon as I opened a VS project/solution, I could check in/out, view history by right clicking on any given file. But suddenly, I dont see those options to checkin checkout etc any more when I right click on a file in VS studio solution explorer.

The team explorer window still brings up the source folder structure and I can get latest or get specific from there but did any one see this kind of behavior? Please let me know what I can do to avoid these situations in future.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Did you lose connection to the TFS server any time recently?  I've had this happen in the past on unreliable network connections when working via TFS remotely.  The solution and all projects therein would "go offline" and would appear to lose their bindings.  This made it particularly unintuitive when the connection was re-established because changes made while "offline" weren't always found.

If you right-click on the solution or the projects, is there an option to "go online"?  You might check the various menus for such an option as well.

Comment: yes there is 'go online' option. I clicked on it and it looked like it got all bindings back.. why did it go offline?

Comment: @ZVenue: If you're connected to the TFS server then yes, definitely.  I've never fully trusted an "offline" TFS solution for tracking changes.  Supposedly the next version of TFS has much better support for a "sometimes connected" model, but current versions treat it very poorly in my opinion.

Comment: @ZVenue: I imagine a number of things can cause it to go offline.  The main pattern I've noticed is when it fails to connect to the TFS server for some reason.  (Maybe when opening the solution, maybe when working on an item in the solution, etc.)  What's particularly bothersome for me is that it tends to do this either quietly (without telling me) or with cryptic and unhelpful error messages.  A simple message saying "TFS server unreachable, would you like to continue in OFFLINE mode?" would be nice, especially if it came with warnings about what actions might cause a risk of losing work.

Comment: true..I agree. Its very silent in the way this happens.. and it can be alarming for some one who experiences this for the first time..

Answer (score 1):

Did you move the source files to a different location on your harddrive, or change your workspace mappings?

Try opening the solution/project by double-clicking the .sln file in Source Control Explorer instead of opening it from windows explorer.

You can also try bringing up the Bindings dialog by going File -> Source Control -> Change Source Control

Comment: Doing this, followed by clicking "Bind" for each of the projects in the dialog, solved the problem for me. A lot of proj/sln files were "changed" (only one having actual changes). Undoing them made the problem come back. Instead, I edited the changes away, then checked in all those non-changes. TFS indicated: "All of the changes were either unmodified files or locks. The changes have been undone by the server." Now everything was bound again, with no unintended modifications.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a very similar experience. I had made several changes which I thought may have influenced my connection resilience. After reversing out of 2 of them and the problem persisted, I finally clocked what it was.

One of the new extensions I am using is NuGet (http://nuget.codeplex.com/). Every time I attempt to add a library my TFS connection fails and is unrecoverable till a restart of VS 2010.

See: http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/725

There is a work around that has been reported and working which may help you even if this is not your problem.

see http://blog.rthand.com/post/2011/08/26/Fixing-combination-of-NuGet-and-Team-Foundation-in-workgroup-configuration-401-Unauthorized.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me also. I was removing a whole bunch of mappings for old releases under the local workspace. It was taking over 40 minutes so I killed it. The mapping has been removed to the older branches but the branch left behind had been disconnected from TFS.